# Macbook accessing remote shared USB drive on Win10

Tags: networking, mac, remote-access, shared-folders

I have a PC base unit connected via ethernet in one location and shared the USB SSD, I am now home (30 miles) and realised I needed a file from the shared drive.

I know the external IP, I know the internal IP, and obviously I know the username/password for Windows.

But when I try to connect through Finder (smb://123.456.7.890) I get an error saying that there was a problem connecting to the server.  It also says that the server "may not exist" or "unavailable at this time.

Does anyone know how to do it or what I should be doing?

Comment: Do you have port forwarding set on your router to allow access to the share on your Win10 computer? Does your firewall allow the connection?

Comment: In addition to Nasir's questions, it would be helpful to know if your ISP allows connections on the SMB ports. Many ISPs block this by default as these are some of the most-attacked ports.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't manually forward any ports as I didn't think about it.  Which ports should I have forwarded?  And should I put it into a DMZ to protect against attacks?